# Using sendfile to copy a file from A to B - illegal seek?

Tags: c, linux

When using the following routine to copy files, I'm getting an "Illegal seek" error.  What could cause that? they are both ordinary files.

```
bool copyfile(const char* src, constchar* dest, bool overwrite_existing)
{
  if (!overwrite_existing && file_exists(dest_filename))
    return false;

  int read_fd;
  int write_fd;
  struct stat stat_buf;
  off_t offset = 0;

  printf("src_filename=%s\n", src_filename.str());

  if (read_fd = open(src_filename, O_RDONLY) == -1)
    return false;

  if (fstat(read_fd, &stat_buf) == -1){
    perror("fstat\n");
    return false;
  }

  write_fd = open(dest_filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, stat_buf.st_mode);
  if (write_fd == -1){
    close(read_fd);
    return false;
  }

  int result = sendfile(write_fd, read_fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
  printf("result=%d, err=%s\n", result,strerror(errno));

  close(read_fd);
  close(write_fd);
  return result > 0;
}
```

Comment: What OS (and heck, for Linux, kernel version) are you using? `sendfile` is notoriously non-standardized, and often picky about the source and destination file descriptor types (early Linux requires the destination to be a socket, all Linux requires the source to be a proper `mmap`-able file, not a "file-like" thing). Side-note: If you just want to read from beginning to end, you don't need to pass `&offset`; at least on Linux, passing `NULL` means "read starting at current file descriptor offset".

Comment: `if (read_fd = open(src_filename, O_RDONLY) == -1)`: `==` has higher precedence than `=`.  So this most likely sets `read_fd` to 0, assuming the `open` succeeds.  Thus you are probably trying to `sendfile` your standard input, which is probably a terminal, which doesn't support `sendfile`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Post that as an answer; that's almost certainly the problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Should I post an answer, or just flag for closure as "typo"?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Both? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (read_fd = open(src_filename, O_RDONLY) == -1)
```

You left out some parentheses.  The `==` operator has higher precedence than `=`.  So assuming `open()` succeeds, you are setting `read_fd` to 0.  Thus your `sendfile` is trying to read from standard input, which probably isn't a regular file.  `sendfile` only supports reading from regular files.  Hence failure.

Compiling with `gcc -Wall` will give you a warning about this: `suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value`.

## Always use compiler warnings, and never ignore them!